# Button color getting changed once I click anywhere on the page, using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button called search at first time I click the color of button will become blue. Second time once I click anywhere on the page button color coming to its original state/color(white). How do I stop it from getting changed from blue to original color using jQuery.

```
<div id="dataTableDiv">
<input type="hidden" id="count" name="count" />
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
    class="display" id="datatable2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>(</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Conditions</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>)</th>
            <th>AND/OR</th>                             
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
<br clear="all" /> <input type="button" name="searchButton"
    id="searchButton" value="Search" /> <input type="button"
    name="resetButton" id="resetButton" value="Reset" />
 </div>
```

Above is some part of the code. Please help!

Comment: what did you try with jQuery?

Comment: Which part of jQuery you want, cause it has lot of code. you are looking on click of search button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking. check this 
[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cp2vbjt0/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#searchButton').click(function(e) {
        $(this).addClass("btnactive");
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.id != "searchButton") {
            $('input#searchButton').removeClass("btnactive");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.btnactive{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

plain JS: , you should be able to modify if need different colors

```
(function(){
var sb = document.querySelector('input[name=searchButton]');
var first = true;

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (first) {
        sb.style.color='white';
        sb.style.backgroundColor='blue';
        first=false;
    }
    else {
        sb.style.color='black';
        sb.style.backgroundColor='#DDD';
    }
}, false) })();
```

and jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cosmycx/5f9no49f/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="search" value="Search">
<input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset">
```

JS

```
$('#search').click(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#0f0');
})
$('#reset').click(function () {
    $('#search').removeAttr('style');
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/5f9no49f/1/)